# Apply a Global conditional format to UISearchBar, UINavigationController, UIToolbar in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, formatting, uipopovercontroller

I'm applying next global format to my app:

```
-(void)customizeAppearance{

    //Customizing UINavigationBar
    UIImage *navigationbarImage44 = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"navigationbar_44"]
                                resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
    UIImage *navigationbarImage32 = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"navigationbar_32"]
                                resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];

    //Set the background image for *all* UINavigationBars
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:navigationbarImage44 forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:navigationbarImage32 forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsLandscapePhone];

    //Customize the titlebar for *all* the navigationBars
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                          [UIColor colorWithRed:255.0/255.0 green:255.0/255.0 blue:255.0/255.0 alpha:1.0],  UITextAttributeTextColor,
                                                          [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.8],  UITextAttributeTextShadowColor,
                                                          [NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(0, -1)],          UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset,
                                                          [UIFont fontWithName:labelFontName size:0.0],             UITextAttributeFont,
                                                          nil]];




    //Customizing UIToolbar
    UIImage *toolbarImage44 = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"toolbar_44"]
                                     resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
    UIImage *toolbarImage32 = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"toolbar_32"]
                                     resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];

    [[UIToolbar appearance] setBackgroundImage:toolbarImage44 forToolbarPosition:UIToolbarPositionAny
                                    barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    [[UIToolbar appearance] setBackgroundImage:toolbarImage32 forToolbarPosition:UIToolbarPositionAny
                                    barMetrics:UIBarMetricsLandscapePhone];

    //Customizing UIBarButtonItem
    UIImage *button30 = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"buttonitem_30"]
                         resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 5, 0, 5)];
    UIImage *button24 = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"buttonitem_24"]
                         resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 5, 0, 5)];


    [[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackgroundImage:button30 forState:UIControlStateNormal
                                          barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    [[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackgroundImage:button24 forState:UIControlStateNormal
                                          barMetrics:UIBarMetricsLandscapePhone];


    //Customizing UIBarButtonItem BackButton
    [[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:
     [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
      [UIColor colorWithRed:255.0/255.0 green:255.0/255.0 blue:255.0/255.0 alpha:1.0],  UITextAttributeTextColor,
      [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.8],  UITextAttributeTextShadowColor,
      [NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(0, 1)],           UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset,
      [UIFont fontWithName:labelFontName size:0.0],     UITextAttributeFont,
      nil]forState:UIControlStateNormal];


    UIImage *buttonBack30 = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"backbuttonitem_30"]
                             resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 13, 0, 5)];
    UIImage *buttonBack24 = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"backbuttonitem_24"]
                             resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 12, 0, 5)];
    [[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonBackgroundImage:buttonBack30
                                                      forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    [[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonBackgroundImage:buttonBack24
                                                      forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsLandscapePhone];


    //Customizing UISegmentedControl
    [[UISegmentedControl appearance] setTintColor:(UIColorFromRGB(toolbarTintColor))];

    //Customizing UISearchBar
    [[UISearchBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:navigationbarImage44];
}
```

and I'm calling this at my AppDelegate.m method

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions{

    [self customizeAppearance];
    return YES;
}
```

The question is:

How do I condition all this general format if the viewController is not inside an iPad popup???[image]

I don't want my popups to share original format, I want them with UINavigationBars, UIToolbars, UIBarButtonItems.. in black color as always

thanks in advance for the support

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `appearance` you can use `appearanceWhenContainedIn:`. So instead of

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:navigationbarImage44 forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

do

```
[[UINavigationBar appearanceWhenContainedIn:[CustomViewController class]] setBackgroundImage:navigationbarImage44 forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

which will restrict the appearance changes to only `UINavigationBar` instances contained in `CustomViewController`. You may want to check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12592025/ios-6-appearance-when-contained-in-multiple-classes) for clarification on how to use `appearanceWhenContainedIn` for things like `UIBarButtonItem`.