# Customizing UIBarButtonItem apperance with multiple UINavigationBar views

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbaritem

I'm using this:

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UINavigationController class], nil]
 setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                         color ,NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
                         FONT(FONT_REGULAR, 15.0f), NSFontAttributeName,
                         nil] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

To set a color for button in `UINavigationController` on `viewWillAppear:` methods.
My application has 5 main views each with `UINavigationController` grouped under `UITabBar`.

Problem is that when I switch between `UITabBar` views, it goes crazy and it always apply the last initialized view color to all other views. I tripple check code is running when I change with proper parameters it just has no effect on existing buttons.

Is there any other way to set color separately for different `UINavigationController`s ?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `appearanceWhenContainedIn:` method, it changes appearance of all the instances of a class. In Your situation this class is the `UIBarButtonItem`. And you are doing it at `viewWillAppear:` method again and again which causes to change the colors of all your `UIBarButtonItem` objects.

This question gives answer to your problem:

[iOS 6 appearance when contained in multiple classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12592025/ios-6-appearance-when-contained-in-multiple-classes)

**EDIT:**

As a solution you can use `tintColor` property for exact `UIBarButtonItem` object.

```
myBarButtonItem.tintColor = [UIColor blueColor];
```

Comment: But I want to change it again and again, just for a diffferent colors on different tabs. How can I change that ?

Comment: use **tintColor** property for exact **UIBarButtonItem** objects